# Is there a reason why not all defined classes end up in the compiled CSS file?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, yeoman

I have a style.scss file containing `@import "partials/module/all"`, and `partials/module/_all.scss` contains `@import "buttons"`, and `partials/module/_buttons.scss` contains a class named `btn--no-link`. This class is not included in the compiled CSS file, however other classes in the _buttons.scss file are.

The weird thing is, I'm using Yeoman to build my project, and when it builds a temporary build for me (when I save an .scss file), all defined classes are included - but when I build a build for production (with the command `yeoman build`), the mentioned class, as well as a few others, are missing from the compiled CSS file.

Are there maybe some command line options that could cause this behaviour? Seems kind of random, except it's the same classes that are missing each time.

Comment: I did not work with `yeoman build` but preferably check your dicatation maybe you forget to add ` . ` at begining of the class name and try replacing ` -- ` with only one ` - `

Comment: But it works fine when compass compiles it for me upon saving a change to an .scss file. So it can't really be anything wrong in the SCSS code itself.

Comment: What are the names of all of the other classes that are missing?

Comment: Actually, so far I've only found one other selector that's missing: `label .is-invalid` which is located in `partials/module/_forms.scss`. Other selectors from both these files are included in the compiled CSS file, but not these two.

Comment: Do these classes contain static CSS or is it dynamic (variables/mixins)?  If the class is generating no content (eg. `label .is-invalid {}`), then it will be removed from the output.

Comment: `btn--no-link` extends some classes defined in another file, `label .is-invalid` is static CSS and not empty. And again, it can't be anything wrong with the code itself, seeing as it works fine when Yeoman runs its compass task when I save edits to a SASS file, but not when it runs the compass task during project build. It runs the grunt task `compass:dist` in both cases, and both produce the same log output - but for some reason they produce different CSS files.